# bool pointer member behaviour different on assigning true vs false

Tags: c++, boolean, member

i use simple bool pointer class member. Assigning false resp. true behaves different - see comments in code. 
I outcomment one to test the other below.

I use compiler call `g++ -o basic basic.cpp`

```
class Test
{
public:
    int a;
    bool* abool;
};


int main() {
    Test t;

    //t.abool = false;              // WORKS
    //t.abool = true;               // ERROR: cannot convert 'bool' to 'bool*' in assignment - expected IMO; 

    // this should work for both values IMO
    //*(t.abool) = true;            // Segmentation fault
    //*(t.abool) = false;           // Segmentation fault



    cout << t.abool << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because a conversion exists from `false` to `0`. So it becomes `t.abool = 0;` which is initializing `abool` with `NULL`. However, `true` converts to `1` and since you can't initialize the pointer with an absolute integer, you get a compiler error. In the second case (with comment this should work IMO) you will get a seg fault as you are trying to dereference an unitialized pointer which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You're `bool*` hasn't been initialized to point to anything.

You can assign it a null pointer value (which `false` will convert to), or a valid pointer to a `bool` object:

```
bool test;

t.abool = 0; // or NULL
t.abool = &test;
```

Once it's pointing at an actual `bool` object you can assign `bool` value to that object through the pointer:

```
*t.abool = true;
*t.abool = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

false works because false is probably seen as `0` by g++

Comment: There's no probability here, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Any literal of numeric type and value zero can be implicitly converted to a null pointer. `bool` is a numeric type, and `false` has value zero. Non-zero values (such as `true`) can't be implicitly converted to a pointer.